# How can I deny "android:keepScreenOn" to a misbehaving app?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, root-access

There is a misbehaving app (com.funplus.familyfarm) that keeps the screen on even long after it is ever needed (the app re-synchs with server and reloads the interface after some idle period).

> The app is not running in background. It is the active app currently shown on-screen.

It makes my device almost too hot to touch, not to mention the battery drain.

Is there any way for me to deny the "[android:keepScreenOn](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen)" to the app, or to do something (like a Tasker task) to kill it after an idle period?

I am running ICS 4.0.4 and the device is rooted. I have purchased Tasker Pro, but really do not know much how to mess around.

Comment: I am not adding the Tasker tag, because any solution that solves the problem (given the OS version) is acceptable, and tagging it would make people think I want only a Tasker answer.

Comment: [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en_GB)?

Comment: @MrPablo Does greenify work on the current active app?

Comment: Greenify will show you potential apps to hibernate, which you can then select and let it do its thing.

Comment: @MrPablo, I am sorry, my bad for making a huge confusion between keepScreenOn and wakeLock (they are related but two different things). greenify would've worked if it was just a wakelock problem, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

### Xposed Module

Since your device is rooted, you could install the [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and then install a module such as [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings). It lets you tweak settings for an app. In your case, it lets you tweak whether to keep the screen on or not (according to its page, at least).

The Xposed framework has tons of other modules for tweaking the inner workings of Android.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Stephen. I will mess around with Xposed at last... (was skirting Xposed for a long time), but that douche app cannot continue to suck juice like that. (and I really love nobody slapbashed the "just stop using the app" - yet).

Comment: Get Xprivacy. Best exposed module, let's you allow or deny fine grained permissions to each app.

Comment: @Mindwin Just stop using the app. ;)   There we go, order has been restored to the universe. +1 for this, Xposed is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Rex I agree that Xprivacy is awesome, and I would have mentioned it as well. Except that it doesn't have controls over every permission possible, including this particular keepscreenon one. It is designed for privacy (hence the name), not complete control.

Comment: I was daydreaming yesterday, I think what we need is an app called "No you Can't", that would deny everything to apps (subject to users allowing stuff on a per-app basis. Its icon would be that megamind poster. Seriously, users need more POWAAAAA